# Pega dado de um campo específico cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, mvc, framework

Etou começando agora com o CakePHP, e gostaria de saber como pegar o valor de um campo específico.

Por exemplo, tenho os campos nome e email. Como pegar o valor do campo nome?

PS: Sei que tem o método `$this->data`, mas ele pega todos os campos.

O meu formulário está assim:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Usuario', array('action' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('usuario');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('senha', array('type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('ativo');
echo $this->Form->end('Salvar');
```

Comment: Você se refere aos campos de um formulário? Se for, é possível nos mostrar como está o seu formulário?

Comment: Ou, se não for o que disse o Paulo Rodrigues, quer pegar os dados do Model?

Comment: Exato @PauloRodrigues. Nao importa o campo que quero pegar. Apenas quero saber como pegar o valor de um campo individualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está claro em que situação você quer pegar esse dado. Se for o valor do campo após o envio do formulário, geralmente isso se faz no Controller:

```
$usuario = $this->request->data['NomeDoModel']['usuario'];
```

Se for do banco de dados, você consulta pelo model (também a partir do Controller):

```
$usuario = $this->NomeDoModel->find('all', array(
    'fields' => 'usuario',
    'conditions' => "id = 1" // por exemplo
));
echo $usuario[0]['NomeDoModel']['usuario'];
```

Na própria view, se os dados tiverem sido setados no `data` a partir do Controler, você pode acessar diretamente via:

```
$this->data['NomeDoModel']['usuario'];
```

Ou passar numa variável qualquer. Por exemplo, dentro do seu controller, action `index`:

```
function index() {
    this->set(array('dado' => 'bla bla bla'));
}

// e na view:
echo $dado;
```

Comment: Consegui, utilizando o nome do meu controlador seguindo pelo nome do campo.